# Unable to setup MiniProfiler w/ Enity Framework 4.0 (Not code first)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I installed MiniProfiler and MiniProfiler.EF in my project via nuget.

Before using MiniProfiler I would open a connection using this in my model repository:

```
    public class NotificationRepository
    {
       private CBNotificationModel.CB_NotificationEntities db;

       public NotificationRepository()
       {
          db = new CB_NotificationEntities();
       }

       public NotificationContact GetNotificationContacts()
       {
          return db.NotificationContacts.ToList();
       }
    }
```

To use mini profiler I created:

```
  public static class ConnectionHelper
    {
        public static CB_NotificationEntities GetEntityConnection()
        {
            var conn = new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection(GetConnection(), MiniProfiler.Current);

            return ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<CB_NotificationEntities>(conn); // resides in the MiniProfiler.EF nuget pack
        }

        public static EntityConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return new EntityConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CB_NotificationEntities"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

The model repository now uses

```
db = ConnectionHelper.GetEntityConnection();
```

However this gives the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Am I missing a step? I tried adding  MiniProfilerEF.Initialize() and  MiniProfilerEF.Initialize_EF42() in Application_start() however that just changes the errors given.

There does not seem to be much information for setting up a entity framework project to use miniprofiler unless it is codefirst.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get this working by changing my ConnectionHelper class to the following:

```
    public static class ConnectionHelper
    {
            public static CB_NotificationEntities GetEntityConnection()
            {

                var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CB_NotificationEntities"].ConnectionString;
                var ecsb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
                var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ecsb.ProviderConnectionString);
                var pConn = new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection(sqlConn, MiniProfiler.Current);

                var context = ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<CB_NotificationEntities>(pConn);
                return context;

          }
     }
```

Comment: I wish I could give you so many points for this, I looked all over for this

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. Its my 2nd attempt to make the MiniProfiler works and every time I was getting a StackOverflowException. This solution works perfectly.