# Proper way to profile a DbContext using MiniProfiler and EF 5 and Autofac

Tags: autofac, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, mvc-mini-profiler

The [MiniProfiler site](http://miniprofiler.com/) gives the following code for generating an Entity Framework `ObjectContext`:

```
public static MyModel Get()
{
  var conn =  new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection(GetConnection(), MiniProfiler.Current);
  return ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<MyModel>(conn); // resides in the MiniProfiler.EF nuget pack
}
```

However, using Entity Framework 5, I am not using an `ObjectContext` - rather I am using a `DbContext`. I cannot plug the model name in here, since the `CreateObjectContext<T>()` method expects `T` to be of type `ObjectContext`.  (For the same reason, the code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11230573/51) also doesn't work).

Additionally, I am using autofac to initialize my Db connections. This is being registered with the following (`MyData` = the name of my EF DataContext):

```
Builder.RegisterType<MyData>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

So combining two parts: how can I use autofac to initialize my DbContext tied into MiniProfiler.EF? And if that is not possible, at least how can I do the first part (create a factory method for MiniProfiler.EF to return a `DbContext`)?

Comment: I am battling so much with this. Is AutoFac required to get DbContext to work as ObjectContext. When and how do you call MyModel Get()? Do you only call it on database calls you want to profile? Any source or push in the right direction will be so appreciated. I am using EF6 and  need a convenient way to profile my sql database calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) of the `DbContext` class which takes an existing `DbConnection`

So you need a new contructor on your `MyData` which just calls the base

```
public class MyData : DbContext
{
    public MyData(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
    }

    //..
}
```

Then you register your `MyData` with `Register`:

```
builder.Register(c => 
{
   var conn =  new EFProfiledDbConnection(GetConnection(), MiniProfiler.Current);
   return new MyData(conn, true);
}).As<DbContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Answer (score 11):

I just got this working:

```
public static class DbContextUtils
{
    private const BindingFlags PrivateInstance = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

    public static T CreateDbContext<T>() where T : DbContext
    {
        return CreateDbContext<T>(GetProfiledConnection<T>());
    }

    public static T CreateDbContext<T>(this DbConnection connection) where T : DbContext
    {
        var workspace = new MetadataWorkspace(new[] { "res://*/" }, new[] { typeof(T).Assembly });
        var factory = DbProviderServices.GetProviderFactory(connection);

        var itemCollection = workspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace);
        var providerFactoryField = itemCollection.GetType().GetField("_providerFactory", PrivateInstance);
        if (providerFactoryField != null) providerFactoryField.SetValue(itemCollection, factory);

        var ec = new EntityConnection(workspace, connection);

        return CtorCache<T, DbConnection>.Ctor(ec);
    }

    public static DbConnection GetProfiledConnection<T>() where T : DbContext
    {
        var dbConnection = ObjectContextUtils.GetStoreConnection("name=" + typeof(T).Name);
        return new EFProfiledDbConnection(dbConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);
    }

    internal static class CtorCache<TType, TArg> where TType : class
    {
        public static readonly Func<TArg, TType> Ctor;
        static CtorCache()
        {
            var argTypes = new[] { typeof(TArg) };
            var ctor = typeof(TType).GetConstructor(argTypes);
            if (ctor == null)
            {
                Ctor = x => { throw new InvalidOperationException("No suitable constructor defined"); };
            }
            else
            {
                var dm = new DynamicMethod("ctor", typeof(TType), argTypes);
                var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                Ctor = (Func<TArg, TType>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TArg, TType>));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is based on the code in [MiniProfiler's `ObjectContextUtils`](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework/ObjectContextUtils.cs).

You use it like this:

```
builder.Register(c => DbContextUtils.CreateDbContext<MyData>()).As<DbContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

This solution **REQUIRES** your `DbContext` to have a constructor which takes a `DbConnection` and passes it to base, like this:

```
public MyData(DbConnection connection)
    : base(connection, true)
{
}
```

Comment: Trying this and getting an exception: "The space 'SSpace' has no associated collection." when calling CreateDbContet<T>(cn).

Any thoughts?